# Using unsigned int instead of unsigned short changes behaviour

Tags: c, unsigned, short, integer-promotion

I am attempting the `htoi(char*)` function from The C Programming Language by K&R (Excercise 2-3, pg. 43).

The function is meant to convert a hexadecimal string to base 10.

I believe I have it working. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

enum {hexbase = 16};
typedef enum{false, true} bool;

unsigned int htoi(char* s);
bool hasHexPrefix(char* s);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   

    if(argc <= 1) {
        printf("Error: Not enough arguments.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else {
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            unsigned int numericVal = htoi(argv[i]);
            printf("%s => %u\n",argv[i],numericVal);
        }
    }
}

unsigned int htoi(char* s) {
    unsigned int output = 0;
    unsigned int len = (unsigned int)(strlen(s));

    unsigned short int firstIndex = hasHexPrefix(s) ? 2 : 0;

    /* start from the end of the str (least significant digit) and move to front */
    for(int i = len-1; i >= firstIndex; i--) {
        int currentChar = s[i];
        unsigned int correspondingNumericVal = 0;
        if(currentChar >= '0' && currentChar <= '9') {
            correspondingNumericVal = currentChar - '0';
        }else if(currentChar >= 'a' && currentChar <= 'f') {
            correspondingNumericVal = (currentChar - 'a') + 10;
        }else if(currentChar >= 'A' && currentChar <= 'F') {
            correspondingNumericVal = (currentChar - 'A') + 10;
        }else {
            printf("Error. Invalid hex digit: %c.\n",currentChar);
        }
        /* 16^(digitNumber) */
        correspondingNumericVal *= pow(hexbase,(len-1)-i);
        output += correspondingNumericVal;
    }

    return output;
}

bool hasHexPrefix(char* s) {
    if(s[0] == '0')
        if(s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

My issue is with the following line from the `htoi(char*)` function:

```
unsigned short int firstIndex = hasHexPrefix(s) ? 2 : 0;
```

When I remove `short` to make `firstIndex` into an `unsigned int` rather than an `unsigned short int`, I get an infinite loop.

So when I start from the back of `s` in `htoi(char* s)`, `i >= firstIndex` never evaluates to be false.

Why does this happen? Am I missing something trivial or have I done something terribly wrong to cause this undefined behavior?

Comment: Which edition of K&R? 1st?

Comment: This is second edition.

Comment: The title of the question would be terrible even if the program invoked undefined behavior. “Undefined behavior” has a specific meaning in C, it is not appropriate to use just because the program does not do what you want.

Comment: Curious: why use type `unsigned int` in `unsigned int len = (unsigned int)(strlen(s));` when `strlen()` returns type `size_t`?

Comment: @chux I have an irrational fear of `size_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `firstIndex` is `unsigned int`, in `i >= firstIndex` then `i` is converted to `unsigned int` because of the usual arithmetic conversions. So if `i` is negative it becomes a large integer in the comparison expression. When `firstIndex` is `unsigned short int` in `i >= firstIndex`, `firstIndex` is promoted to `int` and two signed integers are compared.

You can change:

```
for(int i = len-1; i >= firstIndex; i--)
```

to

```
for(int i = len-1; i >= (int) firstIndex; i--)
```

to have the same behavior in both cases.

Comment: I would rather do for(unsigned i = len-1; i >= firstIndex; i--)

Comment: @GRC which won't work as you will fall down in the same issue OP had. Take for example a `firstIndex` value of `0`, then `i >= firstIndex` will be always true.

Comment: Another possible structure is `for (unsigned i = len; i--; )`

Comment: `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` promoting to signed `int` has caused so much trouble over the years, in some ways it has turned out to be one of the worst design decisions. (Of course there is no way they could have foreseen all the consequences).

Comment: @ouah you are right :) I would use following i = len-1; i >= firstIndex || i > ~0; --i)